# How to read and then write back a wide string?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I'm trying to read wide string from a terminal and then input it back. I was expecting something like

```
wchar_t input[32];
getn_wstr(input, sizeof(input) -1);
mvaddwstr(1, 0, input);
```

to work. Except it doesn't even compile. Turned out that `getn_wstr` requires `wint_t *`. And `mvaddwstr` requires `wchar_t *`.

I would not expect something this simple to be so difficult. Am I using wrong functions here? Do I really have to convert from `wint_t *` to `wchar_t *`? Am I using this complete wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the ncurses [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wstr.3x.html):

> These  functions are described in *The Single Unix Specification, Version 2*.  No error conditions are defined.  This
>   implementation  returns **`ERR`** if the window pointer is null,
>   or if the lower-level wget_wch call returns  an  **`ERR`**.   In
>   the  latter  case,  an  **`ERR`**  return  without other data is
>   treated as an end-of-file condition, and the returned  array contains a **`WEOF`** followed by a null **`wchar_t`**.
>
> X/Open  curses  documents these functions to pass an array
>   of **`wchar_t`**, but all of the vendors  implement  this  using
>   **`wint_t`**.

The note dates from 2002, after checking Solaris, AIX, Tru64 and HPUX.  There was an exception (SCO) which did not seem to matter.

Input-functions for wide-characters return `wint_t` because they have to represent error-conditions in those values.  Output functions use `wchar_t` because there are no errors.  Fortunately the available implementations use the same size, so a cast should work for you.